# Dictionary look up by value and return rank based on position?

Tags: python, pandas

my base data is a dictionary with keys being countries, and values being a list of names from position 0 to 9.

```
#base data
data
{'Newyork': ['Don Willis',
           'Lewis Hamilton',
           'Kimi Raikkonen',
           'Daniel Ricciardo',
           'Fernando Alonso',
           'Max Verstappen',
           'Nico Hulkenberg',
           'Valtteri Bottas',
           'Stoffel Vandoorne',
           'Carlos Sainz'],
'Chicago': ['Don Willis',
           'Fernando Alonso',...
```

> find_city(name, rank) should, given the name of a contestant and a rank (number 1 rank being index position 0) and, returns a list of all the cities where contestant received a specific rank.

```
find_city("Don Willis", 1) == ["Newyork", "Chicago", "Miami"]
find_city("Lewis Hamilton", 6) == [] #None because Lewis Hamilton never ranked 6 in any of city
```

Here's my attempt so far, but not much progress. Any help?

```
def find_city(name, rank):
    data.get("Newyork",None)
    b=[]
    for i in enumerate(a):
        b.append(i)
    for (i,v) in b:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to enumerate here since the index's are only offset by one we can just subtract 1 from rank and look up with that value

```
def find_city(name, rank):
    l = [k for k in data if data[k][rank - 1] == name]
    if len(l) == 0:
        return None
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def find_city(name, rank):
    city_list = []

    for c, l in data.iteritems():
        if l[rank - 1] == name:
            city_list.append(c)

    return city_list
```

This will loop through each key:value in your data dictionary, and check if the value in that city's result list, at index position (rank - 1 because lists are zero indexed, F-1 drivers are not), matches the `name`. If yes, the key (the cityname) is appended to city_list.

When done, it either returns a list of citys, or, if none found, an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

When solving some of these programming challenges, try to think if you can reframe the question or task at hand in another way.

A more specific or simpler way to frame the task would be:

> Create a function that should check a list at each key of a dictionary, if a value exist on a specific index.

```
data = {...}
def find_city(name, rank):
    keys = []
    for key in data:
        if len(data[key]) < rank:
            raise Exception("You tried to reach an index out of bounds")
        if data[key][rank-1] == name:
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_city(name, rank):
    for i in data:
        try:
             if data[i].index(name) == rank - 1:
                yield i
        except ValueError:
             pass
```

It iterates over data and if the list data[i] has got the name at the rank - 1 it "yields" it
I used try because if the name is not in the data it raises ValueError and the program crashes
P.S. yield returns a generator-like object so after receiving the output you should transform it into a list with the list() function